# How can i import ttf font local file to Vuetify Variables?

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

i trying to add a custom font to Vuetify with a local ttf file, to add it, i tried @font-face but the compiler runs in problems to find the file it work with a @import but the font is not online :c
here is my variable.scss file

```
@font-face {
    font-family: "MyFont";
    src: url("assets/font/myfont.ttf");
}

$body-font-family:  'MyFont', sans-serif;
```

and here is the error

```
./assets/font/MyFont.ttf in ./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--9-oneOf-3-1!./node_modules/postcss-loader/src??ref--9-oneOf-3-2!./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--9-oneOf-3-3!./node_modules/vuetify/src/components/VAlert/VAlert.sass, ./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--9-oneOf-3-1!./node_modules/postcss-loader/src??ref--9-oneOf-3-2!./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--9-oneOf-3-3!./node_modules/vuetify/src/components/VApp/VApp.sass and 91 others
```

it seems to be a problem to find the font but i cannot simply put the ttf file in the node module directory :C

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this problem by prepending `~@` to my font path according to LinusBorg [here](https://forum.vuejs.org/t/loading-local-fonts-with-vue-cli-3/38967/4) and it is now working fine. Yours should be `~@/assets/myfont.ttf`.

Comment: Glad it worked! Kindly mark this as the accepted answer if it helped you solve your problem. Thanks!

Comment: Oh! sorry Im new here hehe, Im on it